# How to delete an Analytics Event from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

How can I delete an Analytics Event from Firebase?

While I am testing I wrote some events in Firebase Analytics. Firebase by default orders all events alphabetically. So these testing events interrupts with original events.

I could arrange them by count to push all the testing events to last. But it makes difficult to find the main events since those are not alphabetically sorted.

I didn't find any options in Firebase dashboard to delete a event. Is there a way to delete the old events from firebase?

Comment: I'm having trouble what an "event" is here. Can you show some code? Or if there is no code, describe what Firebase feature you're using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Firebase analytics event

Comment: See my answer for new information as of 31 May 2018.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is currently no way to delete events once they are logged into Firebase Analytics that I am aware of. However, the events will drift out of the default view (which is set to "last 30 days") as time goes on, or you can switch the time period to a shorter time. As you mentioned, you can also click a column header to sort by some other value or "add filter" to filter by an audience or user property.

Comment: "or you can switch the time period to a shorter time" how to do it?

Comment: There is a drop down menu on the top right corner of the events dashboard. You have a ton of options and you can even set a custom time frame. Your question makes me believe you haven't really taken the time to go through the dashboard properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also there's a big problem regarding that: "you can log up to 500 different Analytics Event types in your app" and they are case sensitive. (see more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=flutter)

Answer (score 25):

You can create a new Firebase project if you want to start from scratch.  It's also a fairly common practice to use one project for experimentation and validation of your analytics implementation and then to switch to your production Firebase project when everything looks good.

Answer (score 1):

As of 31 May 2018, there is an API for this. Doesn't delete individual events, but you should be able to use it to delete all the events collected by a particular app instance:

[User Deletion API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/) `(UserDeletion.userDeletionRequest)`

It was introduced in this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/05/a-few-updates-on-privacy-and-security.html) and the intended purpose (user privacy) is  described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en) (last paragraph).

Unfortunately, based on [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064698/how-do-i-delete-user-analytics-data-from-firebase-using-userdeletionrequestsups), no one seems to have figured out how to get it to work :(

**EDIT**

Turns out that, according to Google, this API does delete events (which technically is what the OP was asking), but since the aggregate total remains visible on the Firebase console, it won't help with the OP's specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete analytics events AFAIK, but on some views you can set up the time interval with the filter at the right-top corner to limit the listed events. In the audience set up you need to rely on typing, I am afraid.

Answer (score -7):

As Steve Ganem suggested the simplest thing you can do to reset the Firebase Analytics data is to register new Firebase project and that in your app. You can also keep the old project around for debugging/development.

Comment: so, there was no need to repeat his answer. Just upvote it