# How to delete user analytics data from Firebase using userDeletionRequests:upsert since "APP_INSTANCE_ID" is marked deprecated?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, upsert, user-data

In the Google Deletion API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/), APP_INSTANCE_ID is now marked as "Deprecated".

In the documentation it is mentioned that the the APP_INSTANCE_ID is only supported if the firebaseProjectId is set which is [deprecated in favor of the propertyId field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/reference/userDeletion/userDeletionRequest.html). Are these fields now equivalent?

Also, if it is deprecated it would be best not to use it anymore, but to use the alternative provided. In this case, what should I use? Another user id type is USER_ID" field, but this redirects to Google Analytics [User ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#set_user_id). Is this the same as [Firebase User ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid)? Can the request be done with Firebase User ID?

Should I should have asked this here to point out the accepted answer might not be the best anymore? [How do I delete user analytics data from Firebase using userDeletionRequests:upsert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064698/how-do-i-delete-user-analytics-data-from-firebase-using-userdeletionrequestsups)