# Is it possible to delete all events in a firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-analytics

We implemented an Android app and we use Firebase events as log events. We also review our logging system thus we created new events. What we would like to do is to delete all the events in order to start from an empty project.
We don't want to create a new project because the app is already in production and deployed to the stores.

Do you know anything about how to accomplish this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451642/how-to-delete-an-analytics-event-from-firebase

Comment: Thank you, but I saw this question earlier this day. I wonder if after 30 days they are actually deleted or they just don't show up

Comment: Try this answer @SaraMenoncin on the linked question. Essential you *can* delete events via the API, but it won't affect the aggregate data, so it may not help you.